# reading a file line by line using the shell

Tags: shell, loops, io-redirection, ifs

the correct syntax to read a .txt file line by line is:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done < input_file
```

I don't understand why it works fine when we put `<input_file` after `done` and go in an infinite loop printing the 1st line of `input_file` when we put `<input_file` after `-r line` in the 1st line shouldn't they be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r line < input_file
do
    echo "$line"
done
```

In this scenario, you are re-initiating the read of input_file with every iteration of the loop. As read reads line by line, each re-initialisation will print the first line. As you never progress past this first line, it will print the first line only indefinitely

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done < input_file
```

In this scenario, the input_file is redirected in to the while loop and then the read line takes place with each line of the redirected output until it gets to the end of the output and then end of the file.

An alternate way of processing the file is to cat file_input through to the while loop:

```
cat input_file | while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done
```

This works in the same way as the previous section but is less efficient due to the pipe. The flow of the output runs from left to right as opposed to right to left. This is often easier to understand. The output of cat input_file is fed (piped) into the while loop and each line is read till the end of the output/file.

Comment: You should not promote useless uses of cat. A useful use would be if there were more than one file to read.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the condition of the `while` (actually a list of commands) is executed and evaluated on *each iteration*, including the redirection. While the redirection after `done` happens only once for the whole loop construct.

So in the first case, `read` always reads the first line of a newly opened `input_file`, while in the second case it keeps reading lines from the same file descriptor (stdin).